# How do I attach a motion activated flood light to stucco?

Tags: light-fixture

I have some simple motion activated battery powered lights that I bought at Costco a while ago. I want to install them outside the house in the front and back. The device comes with a small plastic mount that should go with screws into the wall.

Is there a way to "glue" the device's plastic back to the wall, if the wall is stucco or wood panels? I don't need it to last there forever. If it will hold one year, I don't mind if it falls and I need to clean the surface and glue it again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not recommend gluing it.  If it comes off (wind, animal), it is going to likely pull the stucco off with it in which case you have a big problem and possibly costly repair.

I would just use the screws since it is easier to fill two small holes then fix a large patch of stucco.  Make sure to use screws long enough to penetrate the solid material behind it; at least 1 1/2" wood screws.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  Use a silicon adhesive for temporary use, or a epoxy for permanent use.  Or a top quality outdoor rated double sticky foam tape.

The lights you have don't weigh enough to create any problem.  Just keep in mind they'll only last at most a few years, before having to be disposed of.